# cannot set a breakpoint in visual studio code when it is attached to a running docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I wrote a simple program in javascript and have successfully dockerized it.

The `app.js` has the following content

```
var x = 1;
x++;
console.log(x);
```

The `Dockerfile` has the following content

```
FROM node:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
```

I then run `docker build -t appimage .`  to create the docker image. And run `docker run --name appcontainer -it -d appimage` to spin up the container.

My goal is to be able to open VSCode IDE inside the container and debug code via it. I installed Docker and Dev Container extensions for VSCode and attached it to the running container `appcontainer` created above.

I can open the `/app` folder within container from VSCode, and run `node app` from the integrated terminal. It prints the output correctly.

However, I cannot set a breakpoint in the VSCode. And when I select the variable `x` and right click it, I cannot see options such as `go the definition`. What did I miss?